# Trying to set up permissions for a discord bot but can't seem to be able to

Tags: discord, python-3.6, discord.py

So I'm making a discord bot for a server that I use and wanted to add a censor feature so that if a user said something in the "bannedWords" list while not in a specific channel (working) it would edit the message to have "[redacted]" in its place. I believe the code itself is working but I get this error message every time I test it. I've tried adding permissions via the Discord Developer Portal (selecting "OAuth2," choosing the "bot" scope, and the manage roles, view channels, send messages, manage messages, read message history, and mention everyone permissions), copied the link and added it to my testing server but it still didn't seem to work along with having the proper permissions via role.
Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Productive\Programming Projects\Python 3\Other\MyBot\bot.py", line 32, in on_message
    await message.edit(content = editedMessage)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 843, in edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_message(self.channel.id, self.id, **fields)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 241, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user
```

Code

```py
import discord
bot=discord.Client()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in')
    print("Username: %s" % (bot.user.name))
    print("Userid: %s" % (bot.user.id))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    bannedWords=[...]
    print(str(message))
    print(str(message.content))
    if "name='no-rules-lol'" not in str(message): #probably a better way to do this but it works
        for word in bannedWords:
            if word in message.content.lower():
                await message.channel.send('{0.author.mention}, you have used a word that is black-listed please read <#754763230169006210> to get a full list of black-listed words'.format(message))
                #await message.edit(content = message + 'this has been edited')
                editedMessage=str(message.content.replace(word,'[redacted]'))
                await message.edit(content = editedMessage)

bot.run(Token)
```

Comment: It is impossible to edit another user's message in Discord or the Discord API. There is no such permission, even for admins.

Comment: Oh ok, so the next best thing I assume would just be to delete it?

Comment: Yeah that seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit a message that is not sent by the bot.
Instead, just try deleting the message.

```
await message.delete()
```

It is as easy as that.

If you are adding more commands into your bot, you can just add this to your on_message at last:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Thank you.